# Разметка изображения через таблицу на всю ширину

Tags: html

Имеется одно большое изображение, которое необходимо разделить на несколько маленьких для того, чтобы некоторым придать свойство кнопки. Так как это делается для почтовой рассылки, то было решено верстать через таблицу. Вот что у меня получилось:

http://jsfiddle.net/yn1pzpux/1/

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="160" id="Table_01" width="660">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="100%" width="100%">
      <td height="100%" rowspan="2"><a href="#" ><img alt="" border="0" height="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/jYFsoG/1.png" /></a></td>
      <td colspan="5" height="100%" width="100%"><a href="#" ><img alt="" border="0" height="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/kRUJTG/2.png" width="100%" /></a></td>
      <td height="100%" rowspan="2"><a href="#" ><img alt="" border="0" height="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/enZ7Nb/3.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="100%" width="100%">
      <td height="100%" width="100%"><a href="#"><img alt="" border="0" height="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/m89JTG/4.png" /></a></td>
      <td height="100%" width="100%"><a href="#"><img alt="" border="0" height="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/ctNGFw/5.png" /></a></td>
      <td height="100%" width="100%"><a href="#"><img alt="" border="0" height="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/fsgMhb/6.png" /></a></td>
      <td height="100%" width="100%"><a href="#"><img alt="" border="0" height="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/iyek8G/7.png" /></a></td>
      <td height="100%" width="100%"><a href="#"><img alt="" border="0" height="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/jsRnNb/8.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Как сделать это изображение (таблицу) на всю ширину экрана, но при этом сохранить пропорции изображения (чтобы оно не казалось растянутым)?

JavaScript и современные решения в CSS здесь не подойдут из-за несовместимости почтовых клиентов. Надеюсь ответ будет полезен многим другим, так как в поисковиках нет ответов. Кстати, на jsfiddle.net отображается довольно криво, хотя на пустой странице ровно.

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/06/image-maps-in-html-email/ - поддержка почтовыми клиентами map area

Comment: Не подходит. Значения в map area выставляются в пикселях, а в данном случае изображение резиновое. Наверное сделаю align center для изображения, а пустоту заполню background-color соответствующий изображению. Костыль.